# Inertia must be positive definite

Tags: c++, ode-library

I'm writing a game in C++ using Open Dynamics Engine. When I run it, i get these errors:

```
ODE Message 2: inertia must be positive definite in dMassCheck() File ../../../../../ode/src/mass.cpp Line 53

ODE Message 2: inertia must be positive definite in dMassCheck() File ../../../../../ode/src/mass.cpp Line 53

ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1: assertion "dMassCheck(mass)" failed in dBodySetMass() [../../../../../ode/src/ode.cpp]
```

I have this code:

```
void Physics::addObject(dBodyID *body, dMass *massPtr, dReal mass) {
    *body = dBodyCreate(world);
    dMassSetSphereTotal(massPtr, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    dBodySetMass(*body, massPtr);
    dBodySetPosition(*body, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

I'm calling it by `physics->addObject(&orb.body, &orb.mass, 1.0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `massPtr` structure contains an inertia tensor. This tensor (just a matrix, in this context) has to be positive definite. That's all we can say until you tell us where you got your `massPtr` from.

Comment: Ahhh... Lol, nothing, i just created a variable in Orb class: `class Orb { public: [...] dMass mass; }` And then i'm calling addObject() after creating Orb and Physics objects.

Comment: Heavens, isn't it obvious? You have to initialise `massPtr` with a valid inertia tensor. Like the error messages told you.